# Does wget download files more than once?

Tags: linux, terminal, download, wget

Suppose there is a website where Page A links to Page B and pages A and B both link to page C.

Somthing like

```
A -> B -> C
|
v
C
```

If I run recursive wget on A to begin downloading the pages and their assets, will C get downloaded twice? Or is wget smart enough to know that C has already been downloaded and it won't waste network resources redownloading it?

Comment: Can you not run the experiment yourself and see what happens?

Comment: I can easily run this, but I don't know a good way to tell if the file is downloaded twice and then one copy is deleted, or if only 1 download is every performed.

Comment: ahhh....I believe it does list the files being transferred although check me out it might require a command line flag.  But by examining / saving the log of files downloaded you should be able to make the determination.

Comment: Using the option `-nc` (`--no-clobber`) prevents it from overwriting downloaded files, if they already exist.